# About OpAmp phase-reversal

Tags: operational-amplifier

The link http://www.njr.com/semicon/design_support/faq/10088.html do some explanations about the phase-reversal of OpAmp. And give a figure:

[image]

And the output when phase-reversal occurred:

[image]

It states

> When the base voltage of Q5 falls, the Q5 and Q6 transistor of the next stage cut off. The output stage stays near V+ supply voltage side by connecting a current source to a corrector terminal of Q6.

In what situation will the base of Q5 can fall to make Q5 and Q6 cut off? Assume Q2's emitter is at a fixed voltage, then Vb5 (Q5's base voltage) = Ve2 - Vsat2, will this voltage goes low with the base voltage of Q2?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you recognize Q1 and Q2 as a differential pair feeding a current mirror load Q3/Q4.

The lower of the two differential inputs will cause the related transistor to hog most of the current so the collector voltage will rise- if the transistors remain in the active region. In this case the input voltage is applied to the non-inverting input so a lower input voltage tends to drive the output Vout lower.

However if the input voltage drops below VbeQ5+VbeQ6+VsatQ2-VbeQ2 then the transistor Q2 will be saturated and the collector voltage will be below the voltage required to turn on Q5/Q6, so the output Vout will snap high. Since this is the reverse of the usual action of a non-inverting input, we can call this phase reversal.

Answer (score 1):

> Assume Q2's emitter is at a fixed voltage

Invalid assumption. Q2's Emitter voltage goes up and down with the input signal (one V<sub>BE</sub> drop above it). As the input voltage is brought down, Q2's Emitter voltage will be dragged down with it.

If the input voltage goes low enough then Q2 goes into saturation because its Collector-Emitter voltage becomes less than the Base-Emitter voltage. As V<sub>CE</sub> drops to zero so Collector current must also drop to zero, and Q5 turns off.